# Javascript event after a form has been processed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

How does javascript register a callback to run when the server has completed processing a form? This is my particular setup:

```
<form 
    id="savePlaylistForm" 
    name="savePlaylistForm" 
    target="savePlaylistIFrame"
    method="post"
    action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/savePlaylist">
    <input 
        type="hidden" 
        id="savePlaylistEntire"
        name="savePlaylistEntire" />
</form>
<iframe
    id="savePlaylistIFrame"
    name="savePlaylistIFrame"
    style="display: none">
</iframe>
```

I've tried the following to no avail:

**onSubmit**

Attaching onSubmit to the form is not the right event because onSubmit happens when the client tries to submit. The server hasn't even been contacted yet.

**onLoad**

I attached an onLoad to the target iFrame. It doesn't get fired in my case. My server script sets headers to emulate an m3u playlist file. IFrames only fire onLoad when a normal HTML page is loaded, not when a file save dialog pops up. Even if I were to load a plain HTML page in the iFrame, onLoad would only fire the first time the user submits the form. Subsequent submissions won't fire onLoad.

Comment: I have no idea how the code would look for this, but if you're using an `XMLHttpRequest` object (`xhr`) to submit the data, you should be able to bind an event to the `onreadystatechange` event. In there you should be able to interrogate the returned headers using `xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')` or whatever. Might not even need to interrogate if the `onreadystatechange` event fires and the `readyState == 4`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense though, submitting the form reloads the page with the new response. So your original document wouldn't even exist anymore, so how could it run a callback?

You could just attach an onSubmit handler that cancels the default submission action (by returning false) and replicate the default browser submit by making an Ajax call. Then you have a place to attach a response callback (by listening to onReadyStateChange, or by using something higher-level like jQuery).

Comment: Submitting the form does not refresh the whole page. This is an in-place form submission. I call `$('savePlaylistForm').submit()` and the server response is targeted at the iFrame.

This cannot be replicated with Ajax. Ajax cannot pop up a file save dialog for a PHP output that's emulating a file.